# Rollback in async method that calls another transactional method

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, transactions

I have a non-transactional and asynchronous method that calls other transactional methods of the same service.

I catch an exception if something happens, if something happens, I save the error but the rollback not works.

In this example, to call methods save of Player service, the transaction save the player.

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class PlayerServiceImpl implements PlayerService {

    @Inject
    PlayerRepository playerRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void save(PlayerEntity player) {
        //more code here
        playerRepository.save(player);
    }

    //other methods
}
```

My other service:

```
    @Service
    public class TeamServiceImpl implements TeamService {

        @Inject
        TeamRepository teamRepository;

        @Inject
        MessageRepository messageRepository;

        @Inject
        ErrorRepository errorRepository;    

        @Inject
        PlayerService playerService;    


        @Async("asyncExecutor")
        @Override
        public void saveWithPlayersAsync(TeamEntity team, User user) {

            MessageEntity message = new MessageEntity();

            try {

    //I want rollback this if something wrong happens
                this.savePlayersA(team);
                this.savePlayersB(team);
                message.setContent("Ok !");
            } catch (TeamException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                message.setContent("Fail !");           
                message.setUser(user)
//I save the error for audit
                errorRepository.save(new Error("Fail", user.getCode()));
            } finally {
//always save message for user than execute de function
                messageRepository.save(message);
            }

        }   

        @Transactional(readOnly = false, rollbackFor = TeamException.class)
        private void savePlayersA(TeamEntity team) throws TeamException {
            PlayerEntity p1 = new PlayerEntity();
            p1.setName("Name 1");
            p1.setSurname("Surname 1");
            p1.setTeam(team);
            playerService.save(p1);

            PlayerEntity p2 = new PlayerEntity();
            p2.setName("Name 2");
            p2.setSurname("Surname 2");
            p2.setTeam(team);
            playerService.save(p2);
        }

        @Transactional(readOnly = false, rollbackFor = TeamException.class)
        private void savePlayersB(TeamEntity team) throws TeamException {
            PlayerEntity p3 = new PlayerEntity();
            p3.setName("Name 3");
            p3.setSurname("Surname 3");
            p3.setTeam(team);
            playerService.save(p3);

            PlayerEntity p4 = new PlayerEntity();
            p4.setName("Name 4");
            p4.setSurname("Surname 4");
            p4.setTeam(team);
            playerService.save(p4);

            // here something happens and throw my custom exception
            if (true) {
                throw new TeamException("Fail!");
            }
        }   
    }
```

Why does not the rollback? I put the type of exception in the rollbackFor.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this isn't rolling back for you is because your async method that is calling your transactional method are in the same class. When you annotate the method with @Transaction or @Async the annotation code is handled by the proxy created by spring. When method annotated are in the same class like so, the call to them can't be captured by the proxy to handle the additional request through spring and so the annotation on the method is redundant. You can get by this by having the savePlayer methods in a separate class and have the methods transactional there.